# TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to map over state from redux store and im getting the error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

Im sure the data is coming in correctly but Im not sure if im mapping over this the wrong way to render the contactDetails?.contact?.data?.group?.title Is there a way to grab the group data off the groupDetails? Im a bit of newb at this redux thing and need some help.

I also need to type some more here, let me guess somebody stole your sweetrolls?

Here is my component below.

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  ButtonGroup,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Col,
  Row
} from 'reactstrap';
import ButtonIcon from '../common/ButtonIcon';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { contactById, deleteContact } from '../../actions/index';


const ContactEdit = ({match}) => {

  const ContactId = match.params.id

  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const contactDetails = useSelector((state) => state.contactDetails)
  const { success: successGet } = contactDetails

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(contactById(ContactId))
  }, [successGet])

  const CustomerDetailRow = ({ title, isLastItem, children }) => (
    <Row>
      <Col xs={5} sm={4}>
        <p
          className={classNames('font-weight-semi-bold', {
            'mb-0': isLastItem,
            'mb-1': !isLastItem
          })}
        >
          {title}
        </p>
      </Col>
      <Col>{children}</Col>
    </Row>
  );
  
  CustomerDetailRow.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    isLastItem: PropTypes.bool
  };
  
  CustomerDetailRow.defaultProps = { last: false };

  return (
    <Card className="mb-3">
      <CardBody className="bg-light border-top">     
          <Row>
            <Col lg className="col-xxl-5">
              <h6 className="font-weight-semi-bold ls mb-3 text-uppercase">Contact 
                Details</h6>
              
              <CustomerDetailRow title="Groups" isLastItem>     <----- here is my issue
                {contactDetails.contact.data.group.map( groups => <p className="font-italic text-400 mb-0">{contactDetails?.contact?.data?.group?.title}</p>)}
              </CustomerDetailRow>


            </Col>
          </Row>
        
      </CardBody>
     
    </Card>
    </Card>

  );
};

export default ContactEdit;
```

Comment: You don't seem to reference `groups` in the map callback. From what I can tell the issue is on `contactDetails.contact.data`, it's not defined where you are trying to map the group property. Can you update your question to include your `contactDetails` reducer and how you create your store and provide the redux context?

Comment: Thanks drew... Im a newbie here is the solution.    ```<CustomerDetailRow title="Groups" isLastItem>
                {contactDetails?.contact?.data?.group.map( groups => <p className="font-italic text-400 mb-0">{groups.title}</p>)}
              </CustomerDetailRow> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Drew stated in the comments I was incorrectly referencing groups in the map callback here is the solution below, I also added the ? to give time to load the results

````
<CustomerDetailRow title="Groups" isLastItem>
                {contactDetails?.contact?.data?.group.map(groups => <p className="font-italic text-400 mb-0">{groups.title}</p>)}
              </CustomerDetailRow>```
````